# I am unable to retrieve schema of Clickhouse Database in Talend Open Studio. Can someone guide me?

Tags: talend, clickhouse

I am trying to import a Clickhouse schema in Talend Open Studio ETL software. The steps that I have followed are:

1. I created a connection in Talend Open Studio with ClickHouse using the credentials shown below in screenshot 1.
   [ScreenShot of Connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idNe0.png)
2. In the mapping file option, There is no default file for Clickhouse. That's why I have tried both the Java or Mysql database mapping file and I can create a successful connection with both.
3. While importing schema, the menu shows me the "default" catalog. When I expand it, it lists all the schemas in it. When I select a schema to import, It keeps on retrieving the "Next" button remains disabled as shown in the image below 2.
   [ScreenShot of Retrieving Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhI3x.png)

4. I have also tried by creating a custom mapping file for Clickhouse and importing it in Talend. The content for that file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

-<mapping>


-<dbms default="true" label="Mapping Clickhouse" id="clickhouse_id" product="CLICKHOUSE">


-<dbTypes>

<dbType ignorePre="true" ignoreLen="true" type="String"/>

<dbType ignorePre="true" ignoreLen="true" type="UUID"/>

<dbType ignorePre="true" ignoreLen="true" type="Date"/>

<dbType ignorePre="true" ignoreLen="true" type="DateTime"/>

<dbType ignorePre="true" ignoreLen="true" type="DateTime64"/>

<dbType type="Decimal32" preBeforelen="false" defaultPrecision="10" defaultLength="20"/>

<dbType type="Decimal64" preBeforelen="false" defaultPrecision="10" defaultLength="20"/>

<dbType type="Decimal128" preBeforelen="false" defaultPrecision="10" defaultLength="20"/>

<dbType type="Decimal256" preBeforelen="false" defaultPrecision="10" defaultLength="20"/>

<dbType type="Float64" defaultPrecision="10" defaultLength="20"/>

<dbType ignorePre="true" ignoreLen="true" type="Enum"/>

<dbType type="Float32" defaultPrecision="2"/>

<dbType ignorePre="true" type="Int8"/>

<dbType ignorePre="true" ignoreLen="true" type="UInt8"/>

<dbType ignorePre="true" type="Int16"/>

<dbType ignorePre="true" ignoreLen="true" type="UInt16"/>

<dbType ignorePre="true" type="Int32"/>

<dbType ignorePre="true" ignoreLen="true" type="UInt32"/>

<dbType ignorePre="true" type="Int64"/>

<dbType ignorePre="true" ignoreLen="true" type="UInt64"/>

<dbType ignorePre="true" type="Int128"/>

<dbType ignorePre="true" type="Int256"/>

<dbType ignorePre="true" ignoreLen="true" type="UInt256"/>

<dbType default="true" ignorePre="true" type="FixedString" defaultLength="100"/>

<dbType ignorePre="true" ignoreLen="true" type="LowCardinality"/>
. 
<dbType ignorePre="true" ignoreLen="true" type="Array"/>

<dbType ignorePre="true" ignoreLen="true" type="AggregateFunction"/>

<dbType ignorePre="true" ignoreLen="true" type="Nested"/>

<dbType ignorePre="true" ignoreLen="true" type="Tuple"/>

<dbType ignorePre="true" ignoreLen="true" type="Expression"/>

<dbType ignorePre="true" ignoreLen="true" type="Set"/>

<dbType ignorePre="true" ignoreLen="true" type="Nothing"/>

<dbType ignorePre="true" ignoreLen="true" type="Interval"/>

<dbType ignorePre="true" ignoreLen="true" type="IPv4"/>

<dbType ignorePre="true" ignoreLen="true" type="IPv6"/>

</dbTypes>


-<language name="java">


-<talendToDbTypes>

<!-- Adviced mappings -->


<talendType type="id_List"/>


-<talendType type="id_Boolean">

<dbType default="true" type="UInt8"/>

</talendType>


-<talendType type="id_Character">

<dbType default="true" type="String"/>

<dbType type="FixedString"/>

</talendType>


-<talendType type="id_Date">

<dbType type="Date"/>

<dbType default="true" type="DateTime"/>

<dbType default="true" type="DateTime64"/>

</talendType>


-<talendType type="id_BigDecimal">

<dbType default="true" type="Decimal32"/>

<dbType default="true" type="Decimal64"/>

<dbType default="true" type="Decimal28"/>

<dbType default="true" type="Decimal256"/>

<dbType type="Float64"/>

<dbType type="Float32"/>

</talendType>


-<talendType type="id_Double">

<dbType default="true" type="Decimal32"/>

<dbType default="true" type="Decimal64"/>

<dbType default="true" type="Decimal28"/>

<dbType default="true" type="Decimal256"/>

<dbType type="Float64"/>

<dbType type="Float32"/>

</talendType>


-<talendType type="id_Float">

<dbType default="true" type="Decimal32"/>

<dbType default="true" type="Decimal64"/>

<dbType default="true" type="Decimal28"/>

<dbType default="true" type="Decimal256"/>

<dbType type="Float64"/>

<dbType type="Float32"/>

</talendType>


-<talendType type="id_Integer">

<dbType default="true" type="Int8"/>

<dbType default="true" type="Int16"/>

<dbType default="true" type="Int32"/>

<dbType default="true" type="Int64"/>

<dbType default="true" type="Int128"/>

<dbType default="true" type="Int256"/>

</talendType>


-<talendType type="id_Long">

<dbType default="true" type="Int128"/>

<dbType default="true" type="Int256"/>

</talendType>


-<talendType type="id_Object">

<dbType type="Enum"/>

</talendType>


-<talendType type="id_Short">

<dbType default="true" type="Int8"/>

<dbType default="true" type="Int16"/>

<dbType default="true" type="Int32"/>

<dbType default="true" type="Int64"/>

</talendType>


-<talendType type="id_String">

<dbType default="true" type="String"/>

<dbType type="FixedString"/>

</talendType>

</talendToDbTypes>


-<dbToTalendTypes>


-<dbType type="Int128">

<talendType default="true" type="id_Long"/>

</dbType>


-<dbType type="Int256">

<talendType default="true" type="id_Long"/>

</dbType>


-<dbType type="UInt8">

<talendType default="true" type="id_Boolean"/>

</dbType>


-<dbType type="String">

<talendType default="true" type="id_String"/>

</dbType>


-<dbType type="FixedString">

<talendType default="true" type="id_String"/>

</dbType>


-<dbType type="Date">

<talendType default="true" type="id_Date"/>

</dbType>


-<dbType type="DateTime">

<talendType default="true" type="id_Date"/>

</dbType>


-<dbType type="DateTime64">

<talendType default="true" type="id_Date"/>

</dbType>


-<dbType type="Decimal32">

<talendType default="true" type="id_Float"/>

<talendType type="id_Double"/>

<talendType type="id_BigDecimal"/>

</dbType>


-<dbType type="Decimal64">

<talendType default="true" type="id_Float"/>

<talendType type="id_Double"/>

<talendType type="id_BigDecimal"/>

</dbType>


-<dbType type="Decimal128">

<talendType default="true" type="id_Float"/>

<talendType type="id_Double"/>

<talendType type="id_BigDecimal"/>

</dbType>


-<dbType type="Decimal256">

<talendType default="true" type="id_Float"/>

<talendType type="id_Double"/>

<talendType type="id_BigDecimal"/>

</dbType>


-<dbType type="Float32">

<talendType default="true" type="id_Double"/>

<talendType type="id_BigDecimal"/>

</dbType>


-<dbType type="Float64">

<talendType default="true" type="id_Double"/>

<talendType type="id_BigDecimal"/>

</dbType>


-<dbType type="Enum">

<talendType default="true" type="id_Object"/>

</dbType>


-<dbType type="Int8">

<talendType default="true" type="id_Integer"/>

<talendType type="id_Long"/>

</dbType>


-<dbType type="Int16">

<talendType default="true" type="id_Integer"/>

<talendType type="id_Long"/>

</dbType>


-<dbType type="Int32">

<talendType default="true" type="id_Integer"/>

<talendType type="id_Long"/>

</dbType>


-<dbType type="Int64">

<talendType default="true" type="id_Integer"/>

<talendType type="id_Long"/>

</dbType>


-<dbType type="Int128">

<talendType default="true" type="id_Integer"/>

<talendType type="id_Long"/>

</dbType>


-<dbType type="Int256">

<talendType default="true" type="id_Integer"/>

<talendType type="id_Long"/>

</dbType>


-<dbType type="UInt16">

<talendType default="true" type="id_Integer"/>

<talendType type="id_Long"/>

</dbType>


-<dbType type="UInt32">

<talendType default="true" type="id_Integer"/>

<talendType type="id_Long"/>

</dbType>


-<dbType type="UInt64">

<talendType default="true" type="id_Integer"/>

<talendType type="id_Long"/>

</dbType>


-<dbType type="UInt256">

<talendType default="true" type="id_Integer"/>

<talendType type="id_Long"/>

</dbType>


-<dbType type="Set">

<talendType default="true" type="id_Object"/>

</dbType>

</dbToTalendTypes>

</language>

</dbms>

</mapping>
```

Comment: Hi - if you click the arrow next to the selected Schema name, does it expand to show all the tables etc. within the schema? If it does, are these all shown as being selected?

Comment: The tables are not showing when schema should be expanded.
kindly provide the solution if it is possible.

Comment: I am guessing then that this is a permissions issue. The credentials you are using are not giving you access to the schema/tables. I don't know enough about ClickHouse but normally there are 2 possibilities: you don't have the correct permissions on the actual schema/tables or you don't have the correct permissions on the catalog/information schema